# Optimization - returning filtered elements as std:vector<Class> or std::vector<Intrusive_Ptr<Class>> what is better and why?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I have some doubts about optimization regarding storing elements in vectors and getting information from them. Lets see the example

```
struct Entity
{
public:
    Entity() = default;
    bool isActive = false;
    std::vector<SomeOtherClass> classesThatUseEntity;
}

class Manager
{
public:
Manager() = default;

const std::vector<Entity>& GetOnlyActiveEntity()
{
    std::vector<Entity> value;
    for (const auto& entity : differentSettings)
    {
        if (entity.isActive)
        {
            value.emplace_back();
        }
    }

    return value;
}
private:
std::vector<Entity> differentSettings;

}
```

I was thinking of maybe using a vector of pointers to return values:
`std::vector< boost::intrusive_ptr<Entity>> GetOnlyActiveEntity()`
with this, I got some comments from colleagues that the vector of pointers, in this case, is not the smart option because of heap fragmentation, but I am not sure that this comment is legit. What do you think?

Comment: `const std::vector<Entity>& GetOnlyActiveEntity()` is going to return a dangling reference.

Comment: `GetOnlyActiveEntity` does do what implies in the name.

Comment: Heap fragmentation is a real concern for many kinds of applications.  Especially for apps that use a lot of memory, or apps that are very long lived.  Has heap fragmentation been a problem for your application?

Comment: Can you use C++20?  If so, you could use the ranges library to create a [transfor_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) of the underlying container that is filtered to only show that active elements.

Comment: Do you want to copy the entity? The first one copies the entity and returns the copy.

Comment: You should return a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Entity>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>>` if you don't want to copy the entities. A view or iterator is also a good option.

Comment: Heap fragmentation can be a problem for the application I am working on. 
And I can't use c++20, only 17

Comment: I was looking to avoid making copies into another vector and keep information about those classes in one place, so I created a vector of smart pointers filled with pointers to objects in another vector. My thinking was, that the first vector is reserved and filled on a heap (memory is not fragmented), and then the second vector is also reserved and filled with pointers to spaces in the first vector. But I was told not to do so because copying is more optimal because of move semantics.
I am a little confused about how this can be more optimal, and this is why I wrote here.